# In CQRS how should I handle an aggregate root needing to lookup data

Tags: cqrs

I have an aggregate root that is a plan for picking and packing an order. It will be allocated a bay and that bay must be empty.

I'm going to create a command called AllocateToBay that will indicate which bay should be used. But how should I verify that the bay is in fact empty from inside the order?

I'm thinking what I need is a bay aggregate root, and I need to ask the bay to allocate itself to the order. It could then raise an event to say it is allocated to an order. I would then have a saga perhaps that would listen for this event, and fire the command to the order to let it know which bay it was allocated too. I don't really feel like a bay should be an aggregate root however.

Alternatively I could just "trust" the command, and have something that monitors events to detect duplicate allocations, and it could issue a command to correct any duplicate allocations (I'm guessing this is still a saga)? This way the bay doesn't have to be an aggregate root at least.

It all appears a bit long winded but I can't think of a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If the aggregate root needs to lookup data from outside its own boundary, the usual answer is to pass in a service provider (ie, a domain service) that supports the query.

> I don't really feel like a bay should be an aggregate root however.

Bay is a thing out in the real world, right?  Then it isn't an aggregate root, because the real world, and not your model, controls the "state" of the bay.

> Alternatively I could just "trust" the command, and have something that monitors events to detect duplicate allocations, and it could issue a command to correct any duplicate allocations

Given that you are dealing with validating against state not controlled by your domain model, there's always going to be a risk that your model makes a decision based on stale and inaccurate information about the state of the Bay.  So detecting the *potential* conflict (remember, your detectors are working with stale data too) and escalating is probably going to be important.

That said, it's reasonable to say that your model should only allocate to a bay that it believes is available; especially if the model is significantly more likely to have the updated information, or if the choice of bay is supposed to be part of the state of the aggregate.

Do you want a human operator to be able to insist that the aggregate allocate the work to a bay when the aggregate's model says that the bay is occupied?  This use case probably dictates whether the aggregate checks or trusts the command.

Your think that is watching lots of different events, checking for conflicts, is probably a "process manager", rather than a saga (which is a more complicated thing used in long running transactions; there is a lot of writing out there that confuses the two terms).

Comment: Ok, so should I use a process manager that watches events to discover duplicate bay allocations, or should I pass a domain service to my aggregate root that can query the read tables to see if the bay is empty?